# Image is not opening in new tab

Tags: html, asp.net

I want my image to open in new tab. so for that i have write the code. this is working in IE but not on other browsers like crome, firefox

```
    <asp:HyperLink ID="jpegLink" runat="server" Target="_blank" CssClass="jpegPreview" NavigateUrl="~/myimage.jpg"  ImageUrl="/images/jpeg.jpg" />
```

Comment: why can't you use controller

Comment: controller you means to say Http controller

Comment: it is working perfectly in both IE and Chrome in my side, provide some additional code

Answer (score 0):

`Target="_blank"` is enough to work in both IE and Chrome

Or else you can call it from Javascript like below

```
<asp:HyperLink ID='HyperLink1' runat="server" onclick='openImage();' Text='Click Me'></asp:HyperLink>
```

**Javascript :**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function openImage(hyperlink) {
            window.open("/images/jpeg.jpg", '_blank');
 }
</script>
```